# Python Interpreter not installed after installing Aptana Studio3

Tags: windows-7, aptana, pydev, python

I was under the impression that installing Aptana Studio 3 also installed the python interpreter. when I try to create a PyDev project it says that "Project Interpreter not specified" So it will not let me proceed. Is there any documentation on how to proceed configuring the interpreter for Studio 3? I am using the latest build of Aptana Studio 3 standalone build: 3.0.4.201108101506.

Thanks In advance for any assistance.

PS I have already uninstalled and reinstalled studio 3 and am still having the same issue
I am running it on windows 7 64 bit machine

Answer (score 18):

I'd probably recommend you just download Python from the official site, and configure Aptana to find it.

You can download the latest version of Python from here:

http://www.python.org/download/

You didn't specify whether you were using Python 2.x or Python 3.x? For compatibility reasons, I'd probably go with Python 2.x. The latest 64-bit Windows version of it is 2.7.2., direct link is:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2.amd64.msi

After you've downloaded and installed it, it will place your python interpreter in (assuming you use C:\ as your Windows drive):

```
C:\Python27\Python
```

You simply need to point Aptana to this. To do this, go into preference, then on the left, look for Pydev. Expand that, and look for the section `Interpreter - Python`.

[image: Python Interpreter Selection]

In theory, if you click `Auto Config`, it should automatically detect C:\Python27. If it doesn't, you simply need to click New, then use the File dialog prompt to find `C:\Python27\python.exe`. This will also automatically import all the Python libraries and site-packages you have installed as well (although if this is a fresh install, it'll just be the stdlibs).

Let us know if you have any issues with the above.

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Just confirming, as Victor said, Aptana/PyDev does not ship with a python interpreter (you have to install it separately -- following the steps at http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html should help you to properly configure PyDev -- after you've already installed a Python interpreter in your system).

Comment: @Keith Frank: If the above answered your question, can you please accept - or if not, please elaborate on what else you need.

Thanks,
Victor