# Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105), can not take input in the console

Tags: python, xcode

I'm a new learner for Python and trying to use Xcode to do it, since Xcode looks clean and nice...

I have Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105), should be the newest one.

I follow this [link](https://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/building-and-running-python-scripts-with-xcode-6-1/) to set up Python on Xcode. I think I did right, at least if I give a simple command like

```
print('Hello')
```

Xcode will return me what I want.

But next when I try

```
person = input('Enter your name: ')

print('Hello', person)
```

I see my "Enter your name" shows up in the console.(Lower right box). However, if I put my mouse cursor on it and start typing the cursor doesn't move, and my keystrokes don't show up. But I can see the blinking there so it must have the focus but just not take any input.

I try to search on the web and see some similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426722/python-raw-input-not-taking-input). But they are very old and have no answer.

It shouldn't be a big bug I hope... Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try `raw_input` instead of `input`? does the same happen?

Comment: do you want to stick with XCode? maybe try a different IDE? Aptana, PyCharm, Spyder?

Comment: @CML Yea still the same problem... hmm, I have to stick with Xcode unless there is absolutely no way to code python in it... I know Xcode may not be the best IDE but as a big program, it should be able to program python......I hope......

Comment: I second @CML - there are far better IDE's (which are also free) to develop Python in. Xcode is too Apple centric by definition. I personally can't fault PyCharm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4384935?start=0&tstart=0) the XCode Debugger/Console only allows interaction for programs written in C, C++ and C-Objective.

So I would recommend switching to a different IDE.

Comment: Ok... Any recommendations for other Ide?

Comment: You can use XCode to code, but you could call your Python script from console/Terminal.

Comment: i.c., I already installed IDLE for coding now. It is nice and clean!

Comment: How can I call Python script from terminal?

Comment: cd to the correct directory and then call the script `python script.py` or if you have declared which python interpreter to use within the script you can also do `./script.py`

Answer (score -1):

Update for Xcode 13 and c++ although the same solution may apply to python as the original poser was asking about...

In Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
Make sure you check 'Debug Executable'.
I found that the console would appear, along with all the correct output (std::cout) and the blinking cursor, but it would not accept input.

[screenshot of 'edit scheme' dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVMFw.png)

Comment: *"although the same solution may apply to python"*: it looks like you didn't check it.