# Aptana Error-pydev: Port not bound (found port -1)?

Tags: python, aptana, pydev

I just updated my Aptana Studio3. When I open my python file it says that it can not find `map`, `range` and `filter` and some other methods. but when I run my code, it'll run without any problem. my code completion doesn't work any more. The error for code completion when I use CTRL+SPACE is

```
   Port not bound (found port -1). Is there an enabled firewall?
```

I don't know where the problem is ?!! I searched but I couldn't find a proper solution. I'm using windows 7.

Comment: After recent update i am also facing the same problem. hope we get solution ASAP.

Comment: Where are the Code-Avengers??

Comment: Created ticket for this issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8098

Comment: Please try to add yourself as a watcher to the jira ticket for the ticket, hope these guys will release some update.

Comment: Note that this is an issue only in the Aptana-provided version of PyDev. LiClipse and the latest PyDev do not have this bug.

Comment: I cannot help myself but shout GOOD RIDDANCE. Thanks for forcing me to get rid of that trainwreck.

Comment: I have the same issue with Aptana 3.6. Tried adding the firewall rule, even disabling firewall but didn't help. Any solutions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that this is solved on PyDev and the problem is you can't upgrade PyDev on Aptana 3.6.0. Version 3.6.1 takes out the integration with PyDev and lets you upgrade PyDev.
So I installed Aptana 3.6.1 through Beta repository and then installed the latest PyDev.

Aptana Beta link to add to "Available Software Sites" on Aptana:
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/beta/

Upgrade to Aptana 3.6.1. This will uninstall PyDev.

PyDev link to add to "Available Software Sites" on Aptana:
http://pydev.org/updates

Install PyDev.

And then, "Port not bound" will be solved.

Comment: I migrate to PyCharm but it seems that the solution works for others ! So I accept the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I did trace the differrence between Aptana 3.4 and 3.5, found a forked process to start pycompletionserver at specific ports:

> /usr/bin/python2.7 -u
>   /home/khaled/Downloads/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300/pysrc/pycompletionserver.py
>   48914 48082

In 3.5, this process is not found at all, the version of pydev also changed.

I managed to start the completion server with the same old ports, still Port not bound error occur.

> /usr/bin/python2.7 -u
>   /home/khaled/Downloads/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.0.0.1388187472/pysrc/pycompletionserver.py
>   48914 48082 & [1] 6752

-

> khaled:~/Downloads$ pycompletionserver will start pycompletionserver
>   creating socket pycompletionserver waiting for connection on 127.0.0.1
>   (48914)

Perhaps Aptana has changed the port numbers....

I'm sorry to revert back to 3.4 :-(

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue for some time now. I originally downgraded to the previous release but have now decided to upgrade to the 3.6.1 beta release and this problem seems to be fixed. Instructions on how to upgrade to 3.6.1 [here](http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/beta/).

The PyDev interpreter may not get automatically installed when you upgrade so you'll have to manually install it again. If needed, there are instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314139/python-interpreter-not-installed-after-installing-aptana-studio3).

Answer (score 2):

Using info from idubs11, I was able to get my Aptana 3.6.1(downloaded 2016-03-01) working.  It exhibited the same problem, port not bound.  I was not able to uninstall pydev, until...

1. I added `http://pydev.org/updates` to the installation sites
2. I added `http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/beta/`  to the installation sites
3. Then clicked Help -> Check for updates
4. Installed the update.

Now it was in a weird state, no Pydev anymore and now using the beta version.  I then used the pydev.org install site to install pydev and now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, even with Windows Firewall disabled. I even tried a clean reinstall (version 3.6) to no avail. In the end I was forced to downgrade to [Version 3.4.1](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version#RevertingtoaPreviousVersion-AptanaStudio3.4.1). It's now no longer an issue.

Comment: We are looking for something rather than downgrading! We know that previous versions work great.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the OP asked for help in regards with a Windows OS, however if anyone wants to get this working on OS X 10.9+, then  follow the steps originally suggested by ***daigorocub*** , which are:

> - Aptana Beta link to add to "Available Software Sites" on Aptana
> - Upgrade to Aptana 3.6.1. This will uninstall PyDev.
> - PyDev link to add to "Available Software Sites" on Aptana
> - Install PyDev.

***BUT***, when installing PyDev uncheck *"Show only the latest versions of available software"* check box in Aptana's ***Help > Install New Software*** window and make sure that you choose the latest 2.x.x version of PyDev.

PyDev 3.x+ needs Java JDK 7+ in order to run, however for the latest versions of OS X any Java JDK 7+ is only available as the 64 bit version. Aptana Studio 3 for OS X seems to be available in 32 bit only, which requires a 32 bit JDK.

Another option is to install a 64 bit Eclipse IDE and install Aptana Studio 3.6.1 as a plugin and the latest PyDev separately.

***Note:*** *You will most probably need to download and install the newest version of Java for OS X 2014-001 from Apple. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
This was originally suggested by **ChancePance** in his answer to "OSX Yosemite - JVM Shared library does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol" thread*

Comment: I've added Pydev for Eclipse version 4.4.x after updating to El Capitan... is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 10, I fixed this issue by running the installer again and picked "repair". Fixed this issue for me and did not lose any configuration in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a clean Aptana reinstall had fixed this for me.

Comment: This is not an option here. There are a lot to configure again and we don't want to do that. That's why we have question here.

Comment: I think this is the only way.

Comment: Does absolutely not work in Linux, with Eclipse 3.7/4.3 and any Aptana plugin version starting from 3.5. Does not work either with Aptana 3.5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

After some wasted hours, I just installed [liclipse](http://www.liclipse.com/index.html) and the problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

but have you checked the windows firewall? as it tells the IDE? You should try to put an exception for Aptana and it should work .. in fact it seems that the method of python builtin does not read directly from python but from a db, most likely via a socket on a port closed by the firewall ..

Comment: Do you have any solution??

Comment: have you tried tu add Aptana in exception on firewall? if not ,why your down vote?

Comment: I tried adding Aptana as an exception and go the same error.
Since the error says:
"java.io.IOException: Port not bound (found port -1)" I'm guessing it's a bug in the Aptana update as opposed to a windows setting (since you can't bind to port -1 with or without a firewall)

Comment: Yes added to firewall exception, even i put firewall off.

Comment: Ok, can someone with this error test PyDev standalone? (my guess is that this is something in the bundling in Aptana as they change the code/recompile to use on Java 6) -- so, it'd be nice to have someone with the error check either LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ (PyDev standalone) or Eclipse + latest PyDev (java 7 required in this case) to see if this is actually an issue in PyDev or in Aptana.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Aptana bug! LiClipse works OOTB, but with PyDev 3.3.3, while Aptana 3.6 > 3.0.0