# Apatana Error: "Port not bound (found port -1)"

Tags: editor, aptana, pydev, content-assist

I just installed the default Aptana for python2.7 on a windows 7 machine and I get this error. The dark editor themes are also messed up (letters not showing and colors seems to think its a light background). Content assist is half the reason why I use Aptana, what could b the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aptana Error-pydev: Port not bound (found port -1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065690/aptana-error-pydev-port-not-bound-found-port-1)